# References regarding pragmatic views of philosophy of worklife

Tags: work, pragmatics

I am looking for references regarding pragmatic views of philosophy of  work and worklife.

Comment: When you get some, you probably want to include stuff on the "Ethics of Care" (q.v.) so that you have not chosen too traditionally male a definition of 'work'.  Maybe you can work out from there.  It is women who have been allowed to think through their role in the market of labor most, recently.  Only they are free to ask the question as to whether it is obligatory or not.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty vague. Here are some discussions we've had on this SE. Are you asking for something not covered by these?

[Does a person have the freedom or the right to not work?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22244/does-a-person-have-the-freedom-or-the-right-to-not-work/53741#53741)

[Is work neccessary to be happy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1561/is-work-neccessary-to-be-happy)

[Is society deliberately limiting opportunities for a segment of the population to provide workers?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81483/is-society-deliberately-limiting-opportunities-for-a-segment-of-the-population-t/81490#81490)

[Help to explain the meaning of work beyond the sole purpose of making money](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47606/help-to-explain-the-meaning-of-work-beyond-the-sole-purpose-of-making-money)

[Is a work ethic, ethical?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14487/is-a-work-ethic-ethical)

[Is work a virtual fable?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6455/is-work-a-virtual-fable)

[Is forced labor without pay under poor work conditions , slavery?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23952/is-forced-labor-without-pay-under-poor-work-conditions-slavery)

[Is Work the Root of All Evil?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/22889/is-work-the-root-of-all-evil)

[Arendt : What is the main and intrisic purpose of diffferentiating between "labor" and "work"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/arendt-what-is-the-main-and-intrisic-purpose-of-diffferentiating-between-labo?r)

Buddhism has 'right livelihood', as one of the steps on the  Eightfold Way, which together are the 4th Noble Truth. It's not really systematic, more a kind of guide to contemplating how to subsist ethically, and in alignment with Buddhist priorities.

Play is philosophically interesting, and how it can overlap or not with work. Nietzsche said: "Man's maturity: to have regained the seriousness that he had as a child at play." Feeling autonomous and able to be creative in a job has been shown to reduce stress & link to a longer life.